# reduce diffuse light on shadow catcher (Cycles Render)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, shadows, shadowcatcher

Is there a way to reduce the passive/diffuse shadow only for the shadow catcher? I'm using Cycles Render.

Not that I don't like the cool diffuse shadow, but even for this simple cube render below I have to zoom too far out to remove sharp shadow edges at the edges of the image.

Render:
[image: render]
[image]

Here's the basic file I used: https://cl.ly/c9c748770cc7

Answer (score 1):

try to reduce size to 0 where sun light has option max bounces below,but reduce size of the shadow of the sun to 0

Comment: I've originally used a “Hemi” light, but even when switching to sun and reducing the size to 0 doesn't change things. Though I couldn't find the option for the shadow size. Where can I find this?